# Ionic 4 - check if can go back

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I’m looking for a way to redirect a user back after a click on a button if said back exists, and to a specific route otherwise.

I need to add a condition to my code, but I don’t seem to find a way.

```
  goback() {
    if("something") {
      this.navCtlr.setDirection('back');
      this.location.back();
    }
    else {
      this.router.navigate(['/']);
    }
  }
```

In Ionic 3 we had canGoBack() 1 function… Any idea for Ionic 4? Since it's using Angular router...

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only idea that comes to my mind is using an Angular route guard to allow or restrict going back, even a resolve function would be somewhat helpful.

That and using a navigation history service (RoutingStateService) such as the mentioned in https://blog.hackages.io/our-solution-to-get-a-previous-route-with-angular-5-601c16621cf0 
In the cases I've used the RoutingStateService to handle my navigation history, it has been far more reliable than directly trusting NavigationEnd events (since the RouterStateService uses it inside).

Hope it helps. Best regards.

Answer (score 2):

Since Ionic 4 uses Angular Routing, so you can achieve this functionality the Angular way, you can achieve it by creating a service like this:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, NavigationEnd } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable()
export class PreviousRouteService {

  private previousUrl: string;
  private currentUrl: string;

  constructor(private router: Router) {
    this.currentUrl = this.router.url;
    router.events.subscribe(event => {
      if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {        
        this.previousUrl = this.currentUrl;
        this.currentUrl = event.url;
      };
    });
  }

  public getPreviousUrl() {
    return this.previousUrl;
  }    
}
```

And now inject that service to the component in which you want to check your condition:

In your component:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { PreviousRouteService } from '../services/previous-route.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(private previousRouteService: PreviousRouteService) {}  

  goback() {
    if(this.previousRouteService.getPreviousUrl()) {
      this.navCtlr.setDirection('back');
      this.location.back();
    }
    else {
      this.router.navigate(['/']);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Although, sadly, it doesn't work :( I added a `console.log(this.currentUrl, this.previousUrl, event.url, event instanceof NavigationEnd);` in the function listening to events, and got a very large list of `/item/item_id undefined undefined false` answers, until one true eventually, and then a bunch of others where `this.previousUrl` is (as it should be since it has seen a `NavigationEnd`) the same as `this.currentUrl`. So when `goBack()` gets triggered, it sees a `previousUrl` where it shouldn't - thus not following the desired effect.

Answer (score 2):

Can't you use a `<ion-back-button>` with a `defautHref` ?

```
<ion-back-button defaultHref="/"></ion-back-button>
```

Comment: Hi, seems interesting (I'm not sure if it would work and can't check now, moved on long ago) - although `ion-back-button` doesn't shows up if there is no history I think?

Comment: by adding the `defaultHref`, if there is no history, it "creates" it, so the back button will be there :)

Comment: NIce and easy but can't be prevented or delay with operations before the back action (i.e. save the data before go back)